# IBAction not triggering NSView drawing

Tags: cocoa

I'm missing something fundamental about NSView.  I have a Cocoa Application with an Objective C class named DataSource that is just a regular class, it's not in the nib.  The data source has a single instance variable, an NSColor *, and it has a getter and setter.

The view class instantiates the DataSource in `awakeFromNib`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{
    NSLog(@"awakeFromNib");
    ds = [[DataSource alloc] init];
}
```

and then queries the DataSource for the color to use in drawRect.  It works fine.  I also implement

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *) anEvent;
```

in the view class, change the color of the DataSource, and then call

```
[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

and it also works as I expect when I click in the custom view.

But if I hook up a button in the nib, wired to this IBAction in the view class:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPushed:(id) sender {
    NSLog(@"buttonPushed");
    [ds setData:[NSColor cyanColor]];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

the data source updates, but drawRect is never called, despite `setNeedsDisplay`.  In my more complicated version, if I click in the view (in a way that doesn't change the color), I will then get the update (caused by the button).  Something is delaying drawing.  How can I fix this?

Update:  There is no controller and there are no outlets.  The NSView subclass contains `buttonPushed`.  The data source updates immediately upon button push, but drawing is delayed, despite calling `setNeedsDisplay:YES` from the view class.  Drawing is delayed indefinitely, unless something else happens to trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the IBAction located? Are you using some view controller? Is the NSView an outlet in that controller?